# Quarkus RESTEasy Reavtive - JacksonJsonProvider class missing

Tags: quarkus

We updated Quarkus to 1.11.0.Final and tried to start using the new JAX-RS implementation by updating our dependencies from *quarkus-resteasy* to *quarkus-resteasy-reactive* and from *quarkus-resteasy-jackson* to *quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson*.

In one part of our application, we register providers in a org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Dispatcher mock, created by MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(). Its a part of a unique annotation used tu run our rest-endpoint unit tests.

One of the classes we register is the **com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider**. But that class is no longer present after migrating to RESTEasy reactive.

What should we do about it?

To further clarify what we are doing:

We are not using `@QuarkusTest` to spin up the application, but our own `@ResourceTest` Annotation to test the endpoint. The annotation finds the class under test (cut) annotated with `@ResourceTest.Resource` and finds a Dispatcher declared in the test class. The annotation then uses reflection to set up a Dispatcher instance by registering the endpoints defined in the cut and registering some more providers (like exception mappers) and sets that instance in the test class. The cut is provided by Mockito, with which all our services used by the endpoint are mocked. Calls to dispatcher.invoke(request, response) trigger the endpoints.

```
private static final Class<?>[] providers = {
  JacksonJsonProvider.class,
  ObjectMapperContextResolver.class,
  ...

for (Class<?> provider : providers {
  dispatcher.getProviderFactory().registerProvider(provider)
  ...
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you are doing? Some code maybe?

Comment: OK I see. There is no dispatcher for RESTEasy Reactive, so that approach will not work